# Using Xml-configuration to log to Cosmos DB with serilog

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, serilog, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to go away from statically linking my code to specific serilog sinks and use xml-configuration in appsettings instead.

I used to have code like this:

```
serilogConfig = serilogConfig.WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB(
                    new Uri(logConfig.AzureDocumentDBConfig.Endpoint),
                    logConfig.AzureDocumentDBConfig.AuthKey,
                    logConfig.AzureDocumentDBConfig.Database,
                    logConfig.AzureDocumentDBConfig.Collection);
```

The C#-code to load from appsettings is this:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();
```

I am trying to change this to e.g. this configuration data

```
<add key="serilog:using:AzureDocumentDB" value="Serilog.Sinks.AzureDocumentDB" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.endpointUrl" value="https://my_prefix.documents.azure.com:443/" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.authorizationKey" value="mykey" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.databaseName" value="mydatabasename" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.collectionName" value="mycollectionname" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.timeToLive" value="3600" />
```

My problem: nothing is written to Cosmos.

Am I missing something obvious here? I have checked the config values a million times - and they are correct. I have also tried to use non-existing values for "databaseName" and "collectionName", and serilog creates these artifacts just fine in DocumentDB - to it is able to connect to Cosmos.

And finally - this is the entire code in my test console app:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .CreateLogger();

log.Information("Test");
log.Error(new ApplicationException("some error"), "stuff failed");
log.Warning("Test2");

Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
```

Logging level in app config is this:

```
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
```

Thanks :-)

**UPDATE:**

I have created a completely new Visual Studio project where I am using the fluent configuration API. My code is this:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB("https://myendpoint.documents.azure.com:443/", "mykey")
    .CreateLogger();
```

The behavior is exactly the same. Nothing is written to Cosmos. If I do not specify collection name and database name, a "Logs" collection and a "Diagnostics" database is created in Cosmos - but nothing is written.

I am beginning to question life itself and the meaning with it ... what am I missing here?

For testing purposes I have created a new Cosmos instance and downloaded the "ToDo"-app that writes to the database. This one works, and if I change the pointers to my original Cosmos DB, it can write to this as well. My own code cannot write to the new DB created for test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I was indeed missing something obvious. The application thread ended before data could be pushed/flushed to Cosmos.

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuredocumentdb/issues/82